# docker selenium remote server how to block or whitelist ips

Tags: selenium, security, docker, filter

I set up a docker selenium server for browser testing using [docker selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium)

I run it with:

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -e CHROMEDRIVER_WHITELISTED_IPS='123.123.123.123' -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/standalone-chrome
```

however, since i cannot bind to `127.0.0.1` , the docker server can be used from external ips as well (not only `123.123.123.123`), the whitelist parameter did not werk.

What is a good way to solve this

Answer (score 4):

I'm not entirely sure of what you are trying to do, but I needed to set the whitelisted-ips parameter to allow all IPs for use with the wdio-devtools-service. In order to do this one needs to pass the whitelisted-ips parameter to chromedriver within the docker container. To do that I started it like this to set the whitelisted-ips to an empty value, which then allows all external IPs:

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -p 9222:9222 -e JAVA_OPTS="-Dwebdriver.chrome.whitelistedIps=" -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/standalone-chrome
```